# Fabric js groups the SVG file as a whole, not by the <g> tag

Tags: javascript, html, svg, fabricjs

Colleagues, good afternoon! Please tell me there is a task to get SVG to make it interactive. In fact, there are SVG elements in it that the user can select. SVG itself consists of  tags of SVG groups. The problem is the following, I use fabric js and I want to use it to make this SVG interactive, but I ran into trouble that when loading SVG as a group, the whole SVG is considered a group. I tried to divide all the groups into separate SVGs and process them through fabric js, but then the group of elements has the same size as the frame. Maybe someone has encountered and can help how to get around it?

[image]

I've been reading on the Internet and I can't find a solution to this problem. I tried to load groups separately, but still failed, the frame always remains the same size, if you load as not grouped, then positioning relative to the file is lost. There is one of the elements in the picture, and there are usually 10 of them.

Comment: Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)